# Unable to connect to kafka brokers by ssl - Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm trying to start new project with `spring.boot version: 2.1.5.RELEASE` and `Kafka version: 2.0.1` and faced with problem, that I can't connect to my kafka remote broker by SSL.

At the same time my old project with `spring.boot version: 2.0.1.RELEASE` and `Kafka version: 1.0.1` works fine.

**application.yml**

```
  spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: my-kafka:9093
          autoCreateTopics: false
        bindings:
          customers-in:
            destination: customers
            contentType: application/json
          customers-out:
            destination: customers
            contentType: application/json
  kafka:
    ssl:
      protocol: SSL
      trust-store-location: guest.truststore
      trust-store-password: 123456
      key-password: 123456
      key-store-location: guest.keystore
      key-store-password: 123456
```

Got such **error message:**

```
2019-06-10 17:59:03.636 ERROR 30220 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.b.k.p.KafkaTopicProvisioner      : Failed to obtain partition information

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
```

Old project properties (everesing works fine)

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=my-kafka:9093
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.[group.id]=group_23_spring-kafka

# SSL
spring.kafka.properties.[security.protocol]=SSL
spring.kafka.ssl.trust-store-location=guest.truststore
spring.kafka.ssl.trust-store-password=123456
spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-password=123456
spring.kafka.ssl.key-store-location=guest.keystore
spring.kafka.ssl.key-password=123456
```

Also if I update my working project with

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

it produces the same error

My kafka INFO log Producer config for new and old versions looks almost the same

**new** config `kafka version: 2.0.1` `spring-boot version: 2.1.5.REALIZE`

```
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [kafka-sbox.epm-eco.projects.epam.com:9093]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.id =
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 0
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = SSL
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm =
    ssl.key.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = guest.keystore
    ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location =guest.truststore
    ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

old config `kafka version: 1.0.1` `spring-boot version: 2.0.1.REALIZE`

```
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [kafka-sbox.epm-eco.projects.epam.com:9093]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.id = 
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = null
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 0
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = SSL
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    ssl.key.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = guest.keystore
    ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = guest.truststore
    ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

Also I asked the same [question](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/668) at [spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka) github but we didn't found conclusion

Has anyone encountered the same problem? Or maybe know how I have to configure application.yml to be able to connect to my kafka broker by SSL?
Thanks